# sql query date fetching joins

Tags: sql-server

I have below two tables:

**Table 1**: `activity history`

```
activity id   activity date
1              10/12/13 
1              12/12/13
1              23/1/14
2              22/12/13
2              01/01/14
2              04/03/14
```

**Table 2**: `activity log`

```
activity id       activity done
1                 call sent to client
2                 client is not picking
```

May I have a sql query which bring me result like below:

```
activity id  |   activity done           | latest date of activity

    1           call sent to client             23/1/14

    2           client is not picking           04/03/14
```

I am stuck where I have to fetch the latest activity date along with other fields. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write sth like this;

```
SELECT b.ActivityId, b.ActivityDone, MAX(a.ActivityDate) as 'ActivityDate' 
FROM Table2 b 
    INNER JOIN Table1 a ON b.ActivityId = a.ActivityId 
GROUP BY b.ActivityId, b.ActivityDone
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT x.ActivityId, MAX(x.ActivityDate), y.ActivityDone 
    FROM Table2 y 
        INNER JOIN Table1 x ON y.ActivityId = x.ActivityId 
GROUP BY b.ActivityId, b.ActivityDone
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Aggregate function can be used only with `GROUP BY` clausule (we are talking about sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT T2.ActivityID, T2.ActivityLog, MAX(CAST(T1.ActivityDate AS DAte)) AS 'ActivityDate' 
FROM Table2 T2 INNER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T2.ActivityId = T1.ActivityId 
GROUP BY T1.ActivityID,T2.ActivityID, T2.ActivityLog
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/361fc/1)**

**OP:**

```
ACTIVITYID  ACTIVITYLOG            ACTIVITYDATE
1           call sent to client    2014-01-23
2           client is not picking  2014-03-04
```